# why is the light not working?

Tags: light, lighting

I can't figure out why the light isn't casting light on my objects in blender. Please help!The image shows how the light doesn't work at all, and the image looks like this wherever i move the light. I deleted the original light, could there be a setting i have changed while doing so? it was working beforehand.[[image: moves my light around][1]]

Comment: You are in Material Preview mode. Go to the Cycles ( Above the Gizmo in your viewport press the 4th option, now third one is selected. Then change from Eevee to Cycles if it isn't already in the Render Properties (icon looks like some TV)  - on the Right side of your monitor, under the Scene viewport (Where you have cube.001 and so on)

Comment: As Radoon says, you are in Material Preview mode, press Z and choose Rendered Preview